# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["minutes"] not found

Tags: java, json, org.json, jsonexception

This is my JSON object and I am trying to access the minutes from this JSON object but unable to access it, I have also tried writing some code, can anyone please help.

***{"summary":"B.Com; LL.B.(Hons.) 5-Year integrated-MIBCBT802R01","recurrence":["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"],"reminders":{"overrides":[{"method":"email","minutes":1440}],"useDefault":"false"},"attendees":["qatest1@dc01.tcs-itontap.com"],"start":{"dateTime":"2022-10-24T08:40:00+05:30","timeZone":"India+5:30"},"description":"Lecture scheduled for Subject:Down Stream Processing Lab II and Activity: Practical","location":"India","end":{"dateTime":"2022-10-24T09:30:00+05:30","timeZone":"India+5:30"},"id":2300036}***

````
```String remMinutes = new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONObject(jsonFromSolJSON.getJSONObject("reminders")).getJSONArray("overrides").getJSONObject(0)).getInt("minutes")```
````

Err - JSONError:: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["minutes"] not found.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution

```
var jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
var result = jsonObject.getJSONObject("reminders").getJSONArray("overrides");
var minutes = result.getJSONObject(0).get("minutes");
```